# Is scrolling inside a modal bad when it doesn't look like there is more information to view?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, ux-designer

I am currently dealing with lots of modals that contains a lot of forms. One problem I am facing is how to organize the forms, and I have implemented a mostly single column form, unless the forms are related, then they are side by side. Here is a very rough example:

[image]

My worry is that users might think they are finished with the from after filling out the bottom box and hit submit, not knowing that there are more fields underneath it. My question is, should make it wider so that it all fits on a single, non scrollable modal? I would of course only group like items together, but I would probably have to be more liberal on what items can be grouped together.

[image]

I considered adding headers to each group to easier categorize them, but I this will just take up more of the vertical space I am trying to preserve.

[image]

Is it ok to have a modal with lots of information available on scroll, even though the modal doesn't seem to have more items below it on first glance?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about vertical space (because of mobile devices or other reasons), one common solution is to break up the form into sections and instead of scrolling through them you can step through different sections using 'next' and 'previous' buttons.

The reason why you want to show as much of the form as possible is so that the user has a good idea of how much input is required, and whether they are able to complete it all at once (especially if you can't save and come back to it later).

Regardless of how to decide to organize all the information, the principles to keep in mind are to ensure that the user is aware of what's happening, and that they feel in control of the situation. For example, if they don't know that there's more fields to fill in and click on the submit button, it will feel awkward for a lot of errors to pop up because there are empty fields that failed validation.

You might be trying to avoid one issue for the users by designing the form in a particular way, but it is important not to cause other issues that might make the user experience worse. So the best strategy is to go back to how much content you have to display, and work out the best way to let the user know how much content there is, and how easily they can get through it.